# Adobe Embedded API how to show the Comments panel expanded by default

Tags: api, adobe

I can open it by clicking the icon but is there anyway to have it open on load?

```
var customFlags = {
    showToolbar: true,
    showCommentsPanel:true,
    downloadWithAnnotations: true,
    showToolsOnTextSelection: true,
    printWithAnnotations: true,
};
```

adobeDCView.then(adobeViewer => {adobeViewer.getAnnotationManager().then(annotationManager => {annotationManager.setConfig(customFlags).then(() => console.log("Success")).catch(error => console.log(error));
});
});